# Deep Learning loss that enforces high true positive

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, classification, loss-function

I have a binary classification problem, and my main metric that I'm interested in is True Positive.
For now I'm using the BCE loss but it's not giving me good results.

My question is that, is there a loss that helps in this direction, I was thinking of weighting my predictions using adapted weights, something like:

```py
class WeightedBCELoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.binary_loss = nn.BCELoss(reduction="none")

    def forward(self, prediction, gt):
        class_loss = self.binary_loss(prediction, gt)

        weights = torch.ones_like(gt)

        weights[gt >= 0.5] = w_positive
        weights[gt < 0.5] = w_negative

        return torch.mean(weights * class_loss)
```

but I don't know how to choose `w_positive` and `w_negative`.

Is there a good way to choose them? or is there a loss that is adapted to my situation?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you plotting an [ROC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) curve or just picking a 0.5 threshold for positive classification? Note that you can achieve any true positive rate simply by changing your threshold (though the false positive rate at such a threshold may be unacceptable). [Plotting an ROC curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html) will show you the false vs. true positive trade-off of your system at all thresholds.

Comment: Hi @jodag
thanks for your response. Actually yes, I can choose a higher threshold that will give me a better true positive, but if my system is already bad, this will only adapt to it. what I'm looking for is a loss that favors more true positives, and then I can also apply the ROC method, 
I hope that I clarified my point, thank you!